# Monogame Exit() Obsolete for Desktop Program

Tags: exit, monogame

I'm in the process of upgrading my Monogame project to the newest version (3.5).

I've systematically gotten rid of all the insane error messages (so far) except one:

```
Error   9   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Exit()' is obsolete: 'This platform's policy does not allow programmatically closing.'
```

I'm just calling a simple "Exit()" when the user clicks the corresponding sprite in the UI.

```
case click.exit:
  Exit();
  break;
```

Is there a new way of telling the game I want to quit and return to Windows?

Comment: Check [this](http://community.monogame.net/t/make-it-stop-game-exit-deprecated/1749) link to see if it helps.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Thanks, I also saw that earlier.   However, this is not a windows store app, it's just a regular windows program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

I created a new, blank project and used it as a reference to find the correct assembly to use in the existing project.

For me, it was under:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows\MonoGame.Framework.dll

This one wasn't showing up in the reference manager for some reason. I had to manually browse to it.  No more errors about Exit().

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported on certain platforms (Windows Phone, Windows Store, iOS), because it would cause rejection in the app certification. On these platforms, apps must be closed by the user using OS interactions (task switcher, Alt-F4...). For example, [this Windows 8 document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#close) was cited in the MonoGame change. On other platforms, `Exit()` is supported.

Comment: This isn't for a phone app.  Every other PC / Steam game I've played has had a menu with a "quit" option, so I know it's possible.  Expecting the user to use a keyboard shortcut to kill the program will seem like bad UI.  This also doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I mean the "modern" Windows Store apps, updated the answer to clarify. The desktop app version of MonoGame supports calling `Exit()` as before.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  So the new question becomes "why does visual studio think I'm making something other than a desktop program and how do I change it?"  I've got my output type set to "windows application".   Other than that I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Please check the assembly reference, specifically the description and path. I recently had an issue where Visual Studio mistakenly chose the Windows Store version. I fixed it by using the NuGet package instead of an installed copy, adding a hint path to the project file would also work.